# How do I implement Serializable in Kotlin so it also works in Java?

Tags: java, kotlin, serialization, interop

I have some code that I've been using for years in Java, but need it in Kotlin (its interfaces extend collections interfaces).  Some classes are serializable.  When I try the obvious, I get "Cannot access 'Serializable': it is internal in kotlin.io":

```
class Foo(val someField:Int): Serializable {
    companion object {
        private const val serialVersionUID = 20180617104400L
    }
}
```

So, do I just import java.io.Serializable, or will that cause other issues?

Comment: `java.io.Serializable` yes

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> do I just import java.io.Serializable

Yes. Just be aware that Kotlin uses `@Transient` annotation instead of a keyword.

Of course, Java serialization does have its issues, but there's no difference in that respect between Kotlin and Java, and if you are happy with your current code...